# how to insert a sidebar like UI in xp task bar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

The idea is to combine the features of a taksbar on windows xp and 'sidebar' as in windows vista.

This is very useful if we dock the taskbar vertically ( left or right aligned ) on the desktop and give it some suitable width.

Advantages

1. More number of task bar items can stack vertically on taskbar ( as compared to the default horizontal layout )
2. Some portion of the task bar can prove very handy to host a sidebar like UI. e.g. ToDo list ,world time,etc

Ofcourse various widgets availabe out there fro xp are good options but is there any option that is leveraging the realestate in taksbar itself for this purpose. Adding another bar on the screen just leaves less space for the opening windwos.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. Do you want to know how to do it or do you want someone to write it for you?

Comment: as the title suggests..."how to"

Answer (score 0):

You can see [Yahoo Widgets](http://widgets.yahoo.com/).

There already exists a lot of widgets and [you can build](http://widgets.yahoo.com/tools/) one on your own.

Answer (score -1):

You can already [install the Vista side bar in XP](http://joshoon.deviantart.com/art/Windows-Sidebar-Real-one-Pack-75626472?loggedin=1). If you want to develop your own, look into this.